# How to make a button that shows a text or write a text on the site

Tags: html, css, button

I am a beginner of html and php programming language

I made some buttons, and I can't show any text when you press the button
Code for function

```
<script>
    function produsul_cartezian() 
    {
        --

    }
```

echo() function dont work..
and code for button

```
<input type="button" value="Produsul cartezian" onclick="produsul_cartezian()" button class="btn success">
```

[image: site image]

Comment: What do you want to write when the button is clicked? Also, where are you displaying it? Your question is incomplete. Please add more such details.

Comment: You need a place to put the text in your HTML, like a div or p tag. Then in your JavaScript code you need to set the inner HTML to the text you want.

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP (more than you mentioning echo while in a javascript context)? As far as I can see, it's just HTML and JS?

Answer (score 0):

What I think is that you are looking for a javascript code that can show you some text when the button is clicked...

If this is the problem then you must refer to the code given below.
this code contain simple illustration for javascript code and commands...

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <h1>The onclick Event</h1>

  <p>The onclick event is used to trigger a function when an element is clicked on. 
  </p>

  <p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p 
  element with id="demo".</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

You can now edit the button by giving it css class and editing.

Hope it helps!!
regards,
Om Chaudhary